# Notifying every A object holding a reference to a B object that B object has been removed

Tags: java, garbage-collection

It must be really hard to understand what I meant by that title, but I'll try to explain.

We have a class `Person`, which holds various fields: `name`, `surname`, `age` and so on. These are unique characteristics of any given `Person`. However, let's consider, that every `Person` has a field which references another object of class `House`. Some people have it, which means some `House` object reference, others don't, which means a `Null` object reference (sorry about that). Another thing is that we assume that some people live in the same house, which means multiple references to the same `House` from different `Person` objects. So far so good.

Now, we are in a situation where a fiery `Asteroid` object comes flying through the skies and wrecks a beautiful multi-storey `House` object, where lots of `Person` objects resided. `Asteroid` uses `Town` object's reference to this building and sets it to `Null`. However, the poor `Person` objects still think that they have a `House`: `House`'s reference was changed only on `Town`'s level, so it is still in the memory and every resident has a reference to it. Which means that garbage collector cannot get rid of the `House` object and `Person` objects can still use the pseudo existing `House`.

The question I think is clear now. How should we handle such situations?

I thought of using some `boolean` flag: `true` if exists, `false` if doesn't, and when a `Person` comes to the crater which once was their `House`, they set their reference to `Null`, since there is no such object anymore. It provides a solution, yet garbage collector won't be able to get rid of the object, since not every resident has made sure that the `House` doesn't exist.

Another solution might be that a `House` object has an array of references to all `Person` objects residing in it. After the `House` was destroyed, we set all references to `Null`, iterating through the array. Now garbage collector easily gets rid of the object, yet this might be costly: what if it is a skyscraper?

Any other possibilities?

Comment: So, in that case, what is the object path from the stack to the `House` or the `Person`?

Comment: i think the reference to persons living in the house in the house object is the best, and then you set the house in the person to null.Or you can use a map to link house with persons, and use no reference to the house in the person

Comment: Map personHouse<House,ArrayList<Person>> in this way, your two class have no refernece to each other in themselves, loose coupling

Comment: How about using an ID instead of a direct reference, and look up references using a central, shared cache, like `Town`?

Comment: @JoeC `Town` holds references to all `House` objects, so `Person` objects get references to `House` objects from the `Town`, if I correctly understood what you meant by your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flag on House as you said.
To solve problem with garbage collector, just wire House and Person through
[`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).
When object has only weak incoming references it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Keep in mind, that there is no control over when the garbage collector will run and clear the weak reference. Hence, flagging the `House` as destroyed, is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

> Another solution might be that a House object has an array of references to all Person objects residing in it. After the House was destroyed, we set all references to Null, iterating through the array. Now garbage collector easily gets rid of the object, yet this might be costly: what if it is a skyscraper?

It may be costly, but it won't increase the overall cost much.

Concerning memory, if your skyscraper has a list of length N, then there are N persons referencing it. This means that you only doubled the total number of references.

Concerning time, it's about the same: You need to clean N references, but these references must have been set before. So again, you're just doubling the work.

Doubling sounds bad, but you're doubling a possibly small value.

Note that a `WeakReference` isn't free either. Replacing a normal reference  to `House` by a weak reference means one more object, which is more costly than a (strong) reference.

**If you really want to conserve memory, than storing `List<Person>` in `House` is surely the better way.**

It also offers the advantage of having such a list, which may be useful one day. The redundancy is bad, as you always have to keep the forward and backward references in sync.